# Rails: Canceled `rails g migration` command and now I can't run later migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I was trying to change a column datatype and initially wrote a `rails g migration` command to change the column's datatype; however, the process in my terminal window just hung up and appeared to not do anything.  So then I proceeded to make a class migration file without the generate command thinking that would work.  It also hung up... finally found I forgot to comment out a function i was testing in one my initializers and this was causing it to hang.  Problem is now when I run `rake db:migrate` it errors out because of the migration i initially tried to generate.  Below is the error I'm getting. Anyone know how I can solve this? Thanks!

```
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant ChangeColumnInstitutionidToPerson/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in `block in constantize'
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by making sure my class name matched the file name.

Example:

file name:  `20130607135506_change_column_institutionid_to_person.rb`

class name: `ChangeColumnInstitutionidToPerson < ActiveRecord:Migration`